# How to find and print text in key/value pair in python

Tags: python, key-value

I have a script that performs a lot of different test to some network equipment. I want to print only failed message from the output. The key(show bgp summary) is not constant, it can vary. And there can be several massage fields, both in the ‘failed’ section and in the ‘passed’ section.
How can I do this?

```
pprint(checkvalue.test_results)
```

Provide this output:

```
{'show bgp summary': [{'count': {'fail': 2, 'pass': 8},
                       'failed': [{'id': {'peer-address': '10.10.20.20'},
                                   'message': ' The BGP Neighbour 10.10.20.20 '
                                              "was in ['Established'], now "
                                              "it's ['Connect']",
                                   'post': {'peer-address': '10.10.20.20',
                                            'peer-state': ['Connect']},
                                   'post_node_value': ['Connect'],
                                   'pre': {'peer-state': ['Established']},
                                   'pre_node_value': ['Established']},
                                  {'id': {'peer-address': '10.10.10.10'},
                                   'message': ' The BGP Neighbour 10.10.10.10 '
                                              "was in ['Established'], now "
                                              "it's ['Connect']",
                                   'post': {'peer-address': '10.10.10.10',
                                            'peer-state': ['Connect']},
                                   'post_node_value': ['Connect'],
                                   'pre': {'peer-state': ['Established']},
                                   'pre_node_value': ['Established']}],
                       'node_name': 'peer-state',
                       'passed': [{'id': {'peer-address': '111.111.111.111'},
                                   'message': 'BGP State check',
                                   'post': {'peer-address': '111.111.111.111',
                                            'peer-state': ['Established']},
                                   'post_node_value': ['Established'],
                                   'pre': {'peer-state': ['Established']},
                                   'pre_node_value': ['Established']},
                                  {'id': {'peer-address': '0000:0000:0000:00:2'},
                                   'message': 'BGP State check',
                                   'post': {'peer-address': '0000:000:0000:00::2',
                                            'peer-state': ['Active']},
                                   'post_node_value': ['Active'],
                                   'pre': {'peer-state': ['Active']},
                                   'pre_node_value': ['Active']},
                       'result': False,
                       'test_name': 'BGP-peers-estab',
                       'testoperation': 'no-diff',
                       'xpath': 'bgp-peer'}]}
```

I only want to print the message of the tests that fails. Like this:
' The BGP Neighbour 10.10.10.10 '                                              "was in ['Established'], now "
"it's ['Connect']"

Comment: Please include a code snippet of what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all. You point me in the right direction. I'm able to achieve my goals with this:

```
for testname, value in checkvalue.test_results.items():
    for i in checkvalue.test_results[testname][0]['failed']:
        print(i['message'])
```